# Put a shuffled list into a ListBox

Tags: c#, list, random, converters, shuffle

Im trying to put shuffled list objects into a listbox. I don't know if the randomizer works thats why i want to try it with a listbox. The problem is that "cannot convert int to string" i tried different methods to convert it but nothing works... Please help me =)

(The reason with this is im creating a memory that needs to have a "shuffle" button)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> randomList = new List<string>();
    {
        randomList.Add(textBox1.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox2.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox3.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox4.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox5.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox6.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox7.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox8.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox9.Text);
        randomList.Add(textBox10.Text);
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomList.Count; i++) 
    {
        int pos = rnd.Next(i + 1);
        var x = randomList[i];
        randomList[i] = randomList[pos];
        randomList[pos] = x;
        randomList[x].add(listBox1);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how this line

`randomList[x].add(listBox1);` works, or where the `listbox1` came from

```
randomList is a string list and you trying to add listBox1 which won't work
```

But to re-order the list, you can simply do

```
var rand = new Random();
randomList = randomList.OrderBy(l => rand .Next()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method, which will implelements the Fisher-Yates algorithm for shuffling, like the below one:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
    {  
        Random rnd = new Random();  
        int n = list.Count;  
        while (n > 1) {  
            n--;  
            int k = rnd.Next(n + 1);  
            T value = list[k];  
            list[k] = list[n];  
            list[n] = value;  
        }   
    }
}
```

And then use this method

```
randomList.Shuffle();
listbox1.DataSource=randomList; 
listbox1.DataBind();
```

For more information reagarding the Fisher-Yates algorithm, please look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Thank you Christos. but i get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>"

Comment: Please let me check it and I will update my code correspondingly.

Comment: If i removed "randomList =" and just Wrote randomList.Shuffle(); i get no errors. but how do I put it to my "listbox1" after?

Comment: You could write listbox1.DataSource=randomList.Shuffle(); and then listbox1.DataBind();

Comment: Then I get this error "'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Shuffle' and no extension method 'Shuffle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: You have to declare in a seperate file the class I have posted. Then you will be able to use the extension method called Shuffle. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes I have declared the Shuffle method in a separate class as you showed. There i just puted the algoritm...

Comment: Now I just get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object"  theres someting with the return type?

Comment: just give me few minutes and i will be back. thanks for being patient

Comment: ah I updated also my post, I saw what you were meaning. sorry for the confusion.